# Assign Javascript UI widget function to a parameter and execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Even though there are similar questions, I couldn't find the solution of this case.
In javascript, I have two ui widgets (let's call textbox1 and textbox2). My purpose is to write a generic handler for those functionalities. For example instead of doing following code,

```
initialize: function(element, options){

    if(options.isTextbox1){
       return element.textbox1(options);
    }
    return element.textbox2(options);

}
```

I would like to do as following,

```
var mode;
initialize: function(element, options){
    if(element.isTextbox1){
        mode = element.textbox1;
    }
    else{
        mode = element.textbox2;
    }
    return mode(options);
}
```

However, the second code piece is throwing exception as

> Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function

thrown from jquery-ui-1.9.2.

What would be the appopriate way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it.

Here is the usage

```
var mode;
initialize: function(element, options){
    if(element.isTextbox1){
        mode = 'textbox1';
    }
    else{
        mode = 'textbox2';
    }
    return element[mode](options);
}
```